# I didn't insert invoice along with lineitems..while integrated to quickbooks and load the invoices and lineitems

Tags: rest-api

this is my following code...I am not getting invoice as parent and lineitems as child to that invoice.

```
DOM.document doc=new dom.document();
        try{
            doc.load(invoice);
            Dom.XmlNode rootNode=doc.getRootElement();        
            parsexml(rootNode);
            lists.add(inv);
            insert lists;

            lts.add(items);
            insert lts;

        }catch(exception e){
            system.debug(e.getMessage());
        }    
    }
    public void parseXml(DOM.Xmlnode node){
        if(node.getNodeType() == DOM.XMLNodeType.ELEMENT) {
            system.debug(node.getname());            
            if(node.getname()=='Invoice'){
                if(inv!=null)
                    lists.add(inv);
                inv=new Invoice__c();                
            }
            if(node.getName()=='Id')
                inv.Id__c=node.getText().trim();
            if(node.getName()=='TotalAmt')
                inv.TotalAmt__c=decimal.valueOf(node.getText().trim());
            if(node.getName()=='DueDate')
                inv.DueDate__c=Date.valueOf(node.getText().trim());
            if(node.getName()=='Description')
                inv.Description__c=node.getText().trim();            
            if(node.getName()=='TxnDate')
                inv.TxnDate__c=Date.valueof(node.getText().trim());        
            if(node.getName()=='UnitPrice')
                inv.UnitPrice__c=Decimal.valueof(node.getText().trim());
            if(node.getName()=='Qty')
                inv.Qty__c=Decimal.valueof(node.getText().trim());
            if(node.getName()=='Amount')
                inv.Amount__c=Decimal.valueof(node.getText().trim());
            if(node.getName()=='TotalTax')
                inv.TotalTax__c=Decimal.valueof(node.getText().trim());
            if(node.getName()=='Address')
                inv.Address__c=node.getText().trim();
            if(node.getName()=='Balance')
                inv.Balance__c=decimal.valueof(node.getText().trim());
            if(node.getName()=='Line1')
                inv.BilllingAddress__c=node.getText().trim();
            if(node.getName()=='City')
                inv.BilllingAddress__c=inv.BilllingAddress__c+'\n'+node.getText().trim();
            if(node.getName()=='CountrySubDivisionCode')
                inv.BilllingAddress__c=inv.BilllingAddress__c+'\n'+node.getText().trim();
             if(node.getName()=='PostalCode')
                inv.BilllingAddress__c=inv.BilllingAddress__c+'\n'+node.getText().trim();                                                                         
            if(node.getName()=='Line'){               
                if(items!=null)                                                                                     
                lts.add(items);
                 items=new Item__c(); 
                 items.invoice__c=inv.Id;
                system.debug(items.invoice__c);
                }          
            if(node.getName()=='LineNum')
                items.id__c=node.getText();
            if(node.getName()=='Description')
                items.Description__C=node.getText();
             if(node.getName()=='UnitPrice')
                items.UnitPrice__c=Decimal.valueof(node.getText());
            if(node.getName()=='DocNumber')
                inv.DocNumber__c=decimal.valueof(node.getText().trim());

        }
        for(Dom.XMLNode child: node.getChildElements()){
            parsexml(child);                                       
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two logic errors that follow this pattern:

```
if(node.getname()=='Invoice'){ 
    if(inv!=null) 
        lists.add(inv);
    inv=new Invoice__c(); 
}
```

For both invoices and line items, you're only adding the newly-created object to your list *when you find a second one*. If there's only one invoice or line item, the `if (inv!=null)` condition is never reached. You definitely need to rework that logic to add the objects as they are created.

Comment: But all items and invoices are inserted in object.

Comment: I don't understand. What is your question?

Comment: I am integrated with quickbooks.I want to load invoices and line items from quickbooks to salesforce.where invoices are stored as parent object records and line items are stored as childobject records to that invoices..here I insert the invoices and line items but I am not able to get the line items along with parent recordid

Comment: The logic in your code is incorrect, as stated above. I am happy to clarify or focus on specific issues, but I believe that the issues I note above are at least a major part of your problem.

Comment: Any suggestions to modify the code

Comment: I'm not able to write the code for you. You definitely need to fix your logic as I note above.